# shell script has been retrieving from edbplus sql results with echo outputs

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, enterprisedb

I am trying to call **edbplus** to count a table from a command-line linux shell script, but I have been retrieving from edbplus the response number with others outputs in the same response, I am trying to retrieve from it only an integer response number.

```
#!/bin/sh

COUNT=`./edbplus.sh -silent user/password@localhost:5444/mydb<<-EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM MYTABLE
EXIT;
EOF`

echo $COUNT
```

Response:

```
$ echo $COUNT
6-------------------d always takes 2 parameters: variable_name value
```

Do you know how get only the integer number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 1st value is going to be integer. Please try the below commands

echo $COUNT | cut -d - -f 1

(or)

if only one int value if required, then please try

echo $COUNT | cut -c 1

To solve it from EDB perspective:

If the below flags are used in EDB in single line, then the above issue would have caused.

```
SET PAGESIZE 0 
SET FEEDBACK OFF 
SET VERIFY OFF 
SET HEADING OFF 
SET ECHO OFF
```

Kindly update it as above and provide it in individual lines.